# Hibernate with ProjectionList error: cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api, projection

I have problem with returnig list of my objects. I am working with entity class which has `@EmbeddedId` as you can see in my code below, ther are two lines with similar text: `id.*`.

```
Criteria cr = createCriteria(true);
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("id.qwerty", "QWERTY"));

ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.property("id.qwerty"));
projectionList.add(Projections.property("text"));
projectionList.add(Projections.property("id.property"));
cr.setProjection(projectionList);
cr.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(My.class));

List<My> myList = (List<My>) cr.list();

return myList;
```

At line `List<My> messagesList = (List<My>) cr.list();` the below error has occured.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: my.package.dao.domain.My cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
at org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.put(StandardQueryCache.java:104)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.putResultInQueryCache(Loader.java:2274)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2206)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2164)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1706)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
```

How can I defined `Criteria` or `ProjectionList` in this case?

**EDIT**

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class My extends MyEntity<MyPK> {

   @EmbeddedId
   private MyPK id;

   @Column(name = "text", nullable = false)
   protected String text;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "property", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
   protected Option option;

   @Override
   public MyPK getId() {
       return id;
   }

   @Override
   public void setId(MyPK id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   //getters and setter
   //equlas and hashCode
}
```

And `MyPK` class:

```
@Embeddable
public class MyPK implements Serializable {

   @Column(name = "qwerty")
   protected String qwerty;

   @Column(name = "property")
   protected String property;

   //constructors, getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your entity code?

Comment: @AleksandrM : I have edited my question and added my entity code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using setProjection() on your Criteria, then the list() method will return a type of `List<Object>` or `List<Object[]>`, depending on how many properties you have added to your projection list.

This means you will have to do your own creation of My instances.

```
    List<My> myList = new ArrayList<My>();
    for (Object[] row : cr.list()) {
         My m = new My();
         m.setQwerty((String) row[0]);
         // set the rest of the properties
         myList.add(m);
    }
```

I believe the ClassCastException you are seeing is because the `list()` method is returning `Object` instances but you have explicitly asked for `My` instances by setting the ResultTransformer

[Similar question here, answered by JBNizet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605821/aliastobeanresulttransformermydto-class-fails-to-instantiate-mydto)