# Hibernate HQL multiple new objects

Tags: hibernate, hql

I would like to do something like this with an HQL query:

```
SELECT new Table1(a.field1, a.field2, new Table2(b.field1, b.field2, b.field3)) 
FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN a.table2 as b where...
```

Do you know how I can do it?

Comment: Okay, so we don't know how many attributes you Table1 and Table2 have. Anyway, you can find some nice examples here in SO. This could already help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139386/hql-query-using-dot%C2%B4s-in-the-response-parameters

Comment: I have n fields inside my tables. What I want to do is not retrieving any fields, but only fields that I need.
Are we obliged to select fields in HQL and then doing a loop in Java like in your example?

Comment: Is there a more beautiful method than doing a Java loop?

Answer (score 1):

So I've found a pretty solution :

```
SELECT new Table1(a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1, b.field2) 
FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN a.table2 as b where...
```

With a constructor in Table1 like :

```
Table1(afield1, afield2, afield3, bfield1, b.field2) {
   this.afield1 = afield1;
   this.afield2 = afield2;
   this.afield3 = afield3;
   this.table2 = new Table2(bfield1, b.field2);
}
```